# R - Finding all maxima between defined values in binary file

Tags: r, binary, max

Concerning programming language R
Hello,
can anyone help me with my difficult problem:
I have a big binary file and uploaded it in R. The file contains values like:

```
50000  2 7 9 8 27  66000  44 23 7 55 72 2 1 5  70009....
```

I want to create a matrix, where all maxima between the big values (>10000) are listed.

Comment: can you please make an example of your data (reproducible) ? and an expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is represented in an R vector `vec`

```
vec <- c(50000,  2, 7, 9, 8, 27,  66000,  44, 23, 7, 55, 72, 2, 1, 5,  70009)
```

you can use

```
tapply(head(vec, -1), cumsum(head(vec, -1) > 10000), function(x) max(x[-1]))

#  1  2 
# 27 72
```

The maxima for the example data are 27 and 72.

Comment: Wow, it is working! Thank you very much for your help! I am sure this answer is useful for a lot of similar difficulties!

Answer (score 0):

you can:

load the file

```
vector<-as.numeric(read.table(file, sep = ""))
```

and loop through its values

```
maxima<-numeric()
for (i in 2:length(which(vector>10000))){
   maxima[i-1]=max(vector[(which(vector>10000)[i-1]+1):(which(vector>10000)  [i]-1)])
}
```

which results in

```
as.matrix(maxima)
      [,1]
[1,]   27
[2,]   72
```

for the values in your example.